# Item properties is showing SIZE in bytes with commas

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, file-properties

Why Nautilus, while showing the size of a file in bytes is using *commas*?

- Example 739.5 kB (739,530 bytes)

Until 11.04 it was just a clean number...

- Example 739.5 kB (739530 bytes)

Is it possible change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nautilus now follows the local settings of your user, that means that it will use a comma for you, but a point to another user that is using Spanish as his language.

You can't really change it easily. You can change how numbers are formatted for your user, but this will affect all programs. Or you can path and compile nautilus source to get the older behaviour, but it looks like too much work for this little effect.